# Передача объекта между компонентами Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular2

Есть компонент.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {HomeModel} from '../home/home.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-article',
  templateUrl: './article.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./article.component.css']
})
export class ArticleComponent implements OnInit {

  public article: {};

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private homeModel: HomeModel) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
      this.getArticle(params['id']); // из урла парсится айдишка
    });
  };

  getArticle(id) {
    this.homeModel.getArticles().then((articles) => {
      this.article = articles.filter((article) => {
        return article.id == id; // тут из сервиса вытаскивается нужный объект по айдишке и записывается в this.article
      })[0]; // сначала я думал что ошибку тут, т.к. возвращается массив, он добавив [0] ситуация не изменилась. В консоли - объект есть, в шаблоне - `undefined`
      console.log(this.article); // в консоль отлично выводится нужный объект.
    })
  }
}
```

затем в шаблоне:

```
<h2>Article will be here...</h2>
<h6>{{article.title }}</h6>
```

получаем ошибку. Любое свойство из объекта `undefined`.  Я уже и доки пеерчитал пару раз, и другие ресурсы по исследовал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема с ошибкой была в том, что данные получались асинхронно, и так как в компоненте это поле `article` никак не инициализировалось, все падало на попытке обращения к полю `title` у undefined.

Для избежания ошибки. достаточно инициализировать данное поле, например в конструкторе:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
            private homeModel: HomeModel) {
    this.article = {};
}
```

В этом случае использование `ngIf`, добавляющее проверку необязательно.

Альтернативный вариант: использовать так называемый *Elvis operator*

```
<h6>{{article?.title }}</h6>
```

Comment: Вон оно как. @Grundy, снова благодарю, добрый члеловек. А как обьяснить исчезновение ошибки по`ngIf`? При проверке условия свойство проинициализировалось автоматически?

Comment: @Baga, не, в случае `ngIf`, сам `ngIf` проверял что поле например _undefined_ а дальше рендер элемента с ngIf не шел, и соответственно попытки обратиться к полу у undefined не было, поэтому и ошибки не было

Comment: чет все равно не пойму. при использовании проверки не просто НЕ валилась ошибка, а все отрисовывалось. ( рендер шел)

Comment: @Baga, тут суть в том, что асинхронная операция быстро выполнялась. Если сделать ее продолжительнее, можно будет заметить что сначала ничего нет, а потом появляется.

Comment: Я понял, спасибо, что розжевали.

Comment: добрый члеловек, ну я опять с тупыми вопросами) В фильтрах такая же беда с асинхронностью. Делаю пайп, вешаю его на цикл в шаблоне, массив данных в компоненте тоже приходит асинхронно. и валится обишка такая же. Обьяление переменной выше transform() не помогло.

Comment: @Baga, смотри вариант с конструктором.

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось, если добавить условие `*ngIf`, конкретно в моем пример `*ngIf="article"`, то все работает. В примерах конечно была эта проверка, но вот ее обязательное использование, по-моему не указывалось. Может кому-то поможет.